# How to properly use JTA resource recovery method?

Tags: java, jta

I'm trying to understand how to properly invoke `javax.transaction.xa.XAResource.recovery(int)` method. I'm dealing with an environment where I manually invoke XA operations, and do not have a container resource manager.

JavaDocs simply say that there are possible flags values of `TMSTARTRSCAN`, `TMENDRSCAN` and `TMNOFLAGS`, but don't provide an explanation on what happens when any of those flags or combination thereof is used.

I've combed Glassfish code for what they might be doing with the flag values, but didn't find anything helpful there. I've looked at Artemis - it will return all incomplete transactions only when a lone `TMSTARTRSCAN` flag is used. Postgres JDBC is almost the same, except it `TMSTARTRSCAN` can be coupled with `TMENDRSCAN`, everything is returned in one call as well.

I assume that the reason the flags are there is to provide some sort of pagination to the results, in case there are too many unfinished transactions laying around. So, the right way to deal with this would be:

- call `recover()` with `TMSTARTRSCAN`
- call `recover()` with `TMNOFLAGS` until resulting array is empty
- call `recover()` with `TMENDRSCAN`

For all of the above calls, be prepared to handle returned XID values.

But I would love to be pointed to or given an explanation on how this was intended to function.

**UPDATE**

As @kayaman gracefully pointed me to the XA specification from X/Open, I can see that my assumption was probably correct. The standard explains the intended behavior a lot more clearly, but it doesn't apply one to one to Java implementation, due to difference in array size expectations. The standard explains when to not call `recover(TMENDRSCAN)`, but that's not clear in case of Java, and it's not clear whether calling it incorrectly may cause an exception.

Comment: There's always the [Specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009680699/toc.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

This JTA function is particularly unintuitive, as a lot of the design subtleties of the underlying C API from the XA spec got butchered in the translation to Java, on the not entirely correct assumption they were unimportant in a language that handles memory management automatically.

First, it's important to clarify if you're operating from the perspective of a transaction manager, the component which actually invokes the recover method, or the resource manager, the component which implements it. Glassfish is a TM, Artemis and Postgres are RMs.

The TM calls recover in an iteration style, starting with TMSTARTRSCAN (open a new iterator, get the first batch of results), optionally following with TMNOFLAGS (check for further result batches until one comes back empty, indicating the end is reached) and terminating with TMENDRSCAN (close the iterator, allowing the RM to release items held by it).  In practice, the number of in-doubt branches/Xids is small enough that they form only a single batch, so many TMs will simply call TMSTARTRSCAN followed directly with TMENDRSCAN, or even do both in a single call. This can theoretically miss some in-doubt branches, but usually works well enough as the call cycle is repeated periodically and any extras will simply be picked up in the next pass.

The RM implements recover as a stable cursor/iterator, so that it meets the requirements that things don't shift around too much during the iteration. Whilst it can optionally split the in-doubt tx branch into batches to e.g. minimize memory use in the driver, this is not a common optimization for the reasons outlined above.